# Having difficulty finding regression function and conditional variance

Tags: regression, covariance-matrix, conditional-expectation, conditional-variance

The random vector distribution X = (Y, X, Z) is Gaussian with mean µ = (1, 2, 4)<sup>T</sup> and a covariance matrix Σ is equal to:

\begin{pmatrix}
2 & 3 & 1\\
3 & 5 & 2\\
1 & 2 & 6
\end{pmatrix}

How can I calculate regression functions of E(Z|Y) and E(Z|X,Y), and a conditional variance of D(Z|Y) and D(Z|X,Y) ?